# Android : How to write a file to internal memory from a library project?

Tags: android, file-io, permissions

From a android library project sourced to an external app,

`fos = openFileOutput(CFG_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Returns a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

The function is used inside a class extending `Activity`. How can I use the internal memory from this library?